# monitoring one app spread on multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, jmx

Okay, so I have an application that is going to be load balanced on multiple servers. The way I understand monitoring is that you can monitor the one instance of that application on that one server.

For example, srv1:8880 will show different monitoring statistics for srv2:8880. Is there anyway I can create a single monitoring instance for a shared application? So for the above example, say I have a monitor with a count of 5 on srv1 and a count of 3 on srv2 I can combine the two to a single location and have that count be 8.

Edit - I'm thinking I can pull everything from the RMI port but I'm not sure how I can go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to platform or Application MBean server using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), [MC4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mc4j/) or similar tools.  If you want to do custom tasks based on values from multiple mbean servers, connect to each server, and query MBean information.  You can get more details on connecting to MBean Server [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what level of monitoring you need, but [NewRelic RPM](http://support.newrelic.com/kb/java/new-relic-for-java) can tie into the JVM and provide performance metrics and automatic exception tracking.

For more information on what NewRelic does, [see their website](http://newrelic.com/).

Comment: I'm thinking more on the lines of mbean monitoring and managed resources. Not monitoring the health of the application.